# golang command not working even though manually executing it does

Tags: awk, go

I'm trying to execute an `awk` command in my go program (the awk command pulls zip codes for a specified city, San Francisco in this case, from a tab delimited file of California zip codes):

```
cmd := exec.Command(
    "awk",
    "-F",
    "'\\t'",
    "'{if ($4 == \"SAN FRANCISCO\") print $0; }'",
    "zipcodes_ca.txt",
)
fmt.Println(cmd.Args)

var out bytes.Buffer
var stderr bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &out
cmd.Stderr = &stderr

err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(err) + ": " + stderr.String())
    return
}
```

This outputs:

```
[awk -F '\t' '{if ($4 == "SAN FRANCISCO") print $0; }' zipcodes_ca.txt]
exit status 2: awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
         >>> ' <<<
awk: bailing out at source line 1
```

If I take the printed args from the command and just run that as a command `awk -F '\t' '{if ($4 == "SAN FRANCISCO") print $0; }' zipcodes_ca.txt` it works.  But, running it through my go program seems to be having issues.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  I'm guessing I'm escaping things incorrectly, but nothing I try seems to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think that you need single quotes around arguments. They are an artifact of using shell that prevents shell from interpreting argument content. Try without them.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks. I tried pulling the quotes off of the `if` clause but not the `\t` argument.  Pulling the single quotes off of both did the trick!